# Unknown column in where clause of subquery (MySQL)

Tags: mysql, subquery

I am getting an error of "Unknown column `log.courseid`" in the `where` clause of my query (**AND l.courseid=log.courseid**). The objective is to get the difference of MIN and MAX entries per day of a particular user, then get the sum of all these differences across all courses, ordered descending to get the TOP 10.

```
SELECT c.shortname, cc.description, log.courseid, t2.TimeSpent_Hours
FROM mdl_logstore_standard_log log
LEFT JOIN 
(
    SELECT l.courseid,
    DATE_FORMAT(from_unixtime(timecreated), '%b %e %Y') DateBrowsed,
    SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF
        (
            (SELECT MAX(from_unixtime(timecreated)) FROM mdl_logstore_standard_log WHERE userid=l.userid AND courseid=l.courseid AND DATE_FORMAT(from_unixtime(timecreated), '%b %e %Y') = DATE_FORMAT(from_unixtime(l.timecreated), '%b %e %Y')),
            (SELECT MIN(from_unixtime(timecreated)) FROM mdl_logstore_standard_log WHERE userid=l.userid AND courseid=l.courseid AND DATE_FORMAT(from_unixtime(timecreated), '%b %e %Y') = DATE_FORMAT(from_unixtime(l.timecreated), '%b %e %Y'))
        ))))/3600
    AS TimeSpent_Hours
    FROM mdl_logstore_standard_log l 
    WHERE l.action='viewed' and l.target='course' AND l.courseid=log.courseid
    GROUP BY DateBrowsed,l.userid WITH ROLLUP
    HAVING DateBrowsed IS NULL 
) AS t2 ON t2.courseid=log.courseid
JOIN mdl_course c ON c.id=log.courseid
JOIN mdl_course_categories cc ON cc.id=c.category
ORDER BY t2.TimeSpent_Hours DESC
LIMIT 10
```

What have I done wrong?

Comment: You can not accesss the outer tables in the subquery

Comment: any way to revise the script but achieve the same result? thanks.